# async error i want to download sequential with js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, vue.js

I want to download serially but the code is running asynchronously and the files are downloading in parallel.

```js
   function downloadTemp(arr) {
  let counter = 0
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    async function initiate() {
      let output =await Promise.all(
        arr.map(async x => {
          let out = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let uri = `http://stage.????.com/upload/${x.E}`
            request.head(uri, (err, res, body) => {
              if (err) console.log('filehandleconvert1', err);
              request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('temp/' + x.E)).on('close', () => {
                counter++
                console.log(counter)
                resolve(true)
              })
            })
          })
          return true
        }))
      resolve(output)
    }
    initiate()
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "but sync is still kicking in" ?

Comment: its still trys to download all files at the same time but i want to download after its previous download

Comment: Doing things in parallel instead of serial is the **opposite** of being synchronous!

Comment: can ypu please write me an example  how i download the files sequential ?

Comment: There's a perfectly good duplicate linked from the top of the page.

Comment: this is tottaly not related to my question

Comment: It looks like it is exactly the same problem. (Hint: If people think it is the same, then just claiming it isn't doesn't help: You need to explain what makes your problem different in a way that the solutions for the duplicate don't apply).